# Order the lines in a file by the last character on the line

Tags: c#, file, file-io, io

Can you please help me with this:
I want to build a method in C# which will order a lot of files by the following rule
every line contains strings and the last character in every line is an int.
I want to order the lines in the file by this last character, the int.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a couple of lines as an example? Also, is it a 1 digit integer, 2 digits, mixed?

Comment: Single character that represents an int?  Order a lot of files, or a lot of lines?  Is this homework?

Comment: "asdtrtjt 428.1812 290.6577 1" this is a example of a line; the last char is always a number but it can have more than one digit. it is not a homework :) I want to order a lot of files

Comment: and before the number there is always an empty space ' '

Answer (score 4):

To order ascending by the last character, interpreted as an integer you could do:

```
var orderedLines= File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt")
                        .OrderBy(line => Convert.ToInt32(line[line.Length-1]))
                        .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

With the clarification in your comment - integer following a space character, can be more than one digit:

```
var orderedLines= File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt")
                      .OrderBy(line => Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(" ")+1, 
                                                                        line.Length - line.LastIndexOf(" ")-1)))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: whoever downvoted - the clarification that the integer can have more than one digit and comes after a space character hadn't been added before I did the initial answer - I updated to include that requirement

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, where `filename` is the name of your file:

```
// Replace with the actual name of your file
string fileName = "MyFile.txt";

// Read the contents of the file into memory 
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

// Sort the contents of the file based on the number after the last space in each line
var orderedLines = lines.OrderBy(x => Int32.Parse(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(' '))));

// Write the lines back to the file
File.WriteAllText(fileName, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, orderedLines));
```

This is just a rough outline; hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: The integer could have multiple digits.

Comment: The solution works, the orderedLines var containes the lines in the good order. But in my file there is nothing changed? Should I close the file after using File.WriteAllText method?

Comment: sorry my mistake, the filw is successfully created :)

Answer (score 2):

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    pathToWriteTo,
    File.ReadLines(pathToReadFrom)
        .OrderBy(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(' ').Last()))
);
```

If the file is large, this could be ineffective as this method of sorting effectively requires reading the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want more than single digit integers and that you have a separation character between the filename and the rest (we'll call it 'splitChar') which can be any character at all:

```
from string str in File.ReadAllLines(fileName) 
    let split = str.Split(splitChar)
    orderby Int32.Parse(split[split.Count()-1]) 
    select str
```

will get you a sequence of strings in order of the integer value of the last grouping (separated by the split character).

Comment: This piece of code works:   var orderedLines = lines.OrderBy(line => Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1,
                                                             line.Length - line.LastIndexOf(" ") - 1)));
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, orderedLines));
            }    the orderedLines var is good ordered but the file doesn't get changed. Should I close it or something?

Comment: Great, you should accept it if it's helpful, but look carefully at the other options, the higher ratings suggest other people like them better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these links can help you by sorting it the *natural way*:

- [Natural Sorting in C#](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting)
- [Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html)